# How to wait for a blocking thread until a timeout interval is reached

Tags: c, pthreads

I'm trying to write a program that can prevent halting forever on a blocking syscall. Please note that I'm **NOT** trying to solve the halting problem. The program should try to call a blocking syscall, and then give up after a given time interval has exceeded.

I've tried to write a program where I spawn a thread that tries to perform the possibly forever blocking syscall. The MAIN thread waits for a specified time interval for the spawned thread to finish. If the time interval is exceeded, the MAIN thread should give up and continue with other pressing matters.

In the code below The MAIN thread spawns a detached thread to do the work. This is in order to avoid having to join with a thread that has possibly halted forever.

Next the MAIN thread waits for a condition ("I'm finished!") signaled by the spawned thread using `pthread_cond_timedwait` in order to timeout after the specified time interval (given as a program argument) is exceeded.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

struct ThreadData {
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_cond_t cond;
    pthread_mutex_t mutex;
    bool result;
};

static void *ThreadRoutine(void *data) {
    struct ThreadData *thread_data = data;

    puts("THREAD: Locking mutex");
    int ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_data->mutex);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("THREAD: Failed to lock mutex: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return NULL;
    }

    /* Also tried setting cancel state to async, but it did not help */
    // puts("THREAD: Setting cancel state enable");
    // ret = pthread_setcancelstate(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ENABLE, NULL);
    // if (ret != 0) {
    //     printf("Failed to set cancel state enable: %s\n", strerror(ret));
    //     return NULL;
    // }

    // puts("THREAD: Setting cancel type async");
    // ret = pthread_setcanceltype(PTHREAD_CANCEL_ASYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
    // if (ret != 0) {
    //     printf("THREAD: Failed to set cancel type async: %s\n", strerror(ret));
    //     return NULL;
    // }

    puts("THREAD: Blocking for 3 sec");
    sleep(3); /* example blocking syscall */
    thread_data->result = true;

    puts("THREAD: Signalling main thread");
    ret = pthread_cond_signal(&thread_data->cond);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("THREAD: Failed to signal main thread: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return NULL;
    }

    puts("THREAD: Unlocking mutex");
    ret = pthread_mutex_unlock(&thread_data->mutex);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("THREAD: Failed to unlock mutex: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return NULL;
    }

    puts("THREAD: Returning from thread routine");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if (argc <= 1) {
        puts("Missing argument");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    const int timeout = atoi(argv[1]);

    struct ThreadData thread_data;
    thread_data.result = false;

    puts("MAIN: Initializing mutex");
    int ret = pthread_mutex_init(&thread_data.mutex, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to initialize mutex: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Initializing condition");
    ret = pthread_cond_init(&thread_data.cond, NULL);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to initialize condition: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Locking mutex");
    ret = pthread_mutex_lock(&thread_data.mutex);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to lock mutex: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Initializing thread attributes");
    ret = pthread_attr_init(&thread_data.attr);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("Failed to initialize thread attributes\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Setting thread detach state");
    ret = pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&thread_data.attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to set thread detach state: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Creating thread");
    ret = pthread_create(&thread_data.thread, &thread_data.attr, &ThreadRoutine, &thread_data);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to create thread: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Destroying thread attributes");
    ret = pthread_attr_destroy(&thread_data.attr);
    if (ret != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to destroy thread attributes: %s\n", strerror(ret));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    puts("MAIN: Calculating timeout interval");
    struct timespec ts = {0};
    if (clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts) != 0) {
        printf("MAIN: Failed to get current time: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    ts.tv_sec += timeout;

    printf("MAIN: Waiting for thread to finish (timeout: %d sec)\n", timeout);
    ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&thread_data.cond, &thread_data.mutex, &ts);
    switch (ret) {
        case 0:
            printf("MAIN: Thread finished in time; computation evaluated to %s\n", (thread_data.result) ? "true" : "false");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        case ETIMEDOUT:
            puts("MAIN: Thread did not finish in time");
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        default:
            printf("MAIN: Failed to wait for thread to finish: %s", strerror(ret));
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Running this program, it looks like it's blocked on `pthread_cond_timedwait` for longer than the specified timeout interval.

```
$ gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -c main.c -o main.o
$ gcc main.o -o prog -pthread
$ time ./prog 1
MAIN: Initializing mutex
MAIN: Initializing condition
MAIN: Locking mutex
MAIN: Initializing thread attributes
MAIN: Setting thread detach state
MAIN: Creating thread
MAIN: Destroying thread attributes
MAIN: Calculating timeout interval
MAIN: Waiting for thread to finish (timeout: 1 sec)
THREAD: Locking mutex
THREAD: Blocking for 3 sec
THREAD: Signalling main thread
THREAD: Unlocking mutex
THREAD: Returning from thread routine
MAIN: Thread did not finish in time
./prog 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 3.007 total
```

The program correctly outputs that the thread did not finish in time. But according to the `time` command, it looks like the main thread still was blocked until the spawned thread had finished. While I would expect the man thread to continue once the timeout interval was exceeded.

I can't figure out how to implement this using threads. Another option could be to try to implement this using `fork`. But I'd rather use threads if that is possible.

Thanks :)

Comment: `pthread_cond_timedwait()` has to reacquire the mutex before it returns, which it can't do until the thread unlocks it, which doesn't happen till after it finishes sleeping.

Comment: `according to the time command, it looks like the main thread still was blocked until the spawned thread had finished` how did you get that information from time?

Comment: Which syscall are you using in your real code?

Comment: Also, you can't use `pthread_cond_[timed]wait` returning zero as a meaninful. It can return (successfully) even without being signaled. `pthread_cond_[timed]wait` always has be used in a loop that checks an external condition.

Comment: Tip: Errors should be printed to stderr, not stdout. `perror` makes that easy

Comment: Usually the best way to do this is to change the syscall so it is not blocking forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Shawn `pthread_cond_timedwait` has to reacquire the mutex. By releasing the mutex in the spawned thread before calling the "possibly forever" blocking syscall, the code works as expected. Thanks :)

```
$ time ./prog 1
MAIN: Initializing mutex
MAIN: Initializing condition
MAIN: Locking mutex
MAIN: Initializing thread attributes
MAIN: Setting thread detach state
MAIN: Creating thread
MAIN: Destroying thread attributes
MAIN: Calculating timeout interval
MAIN: Waiting for thread to finish (timeout: 1 sec)
THREAD: Locking mutex
THREAD: Unlocking mutex
THREAD: Blocking for 3 sec
MAIN: Thread did not finish in time
./prog 1  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 1.008 total
```

Execution time is now approx 1 second, as I expected.

Comment: Alternative approach: Don't detach the thread. Use `pthread_timedjoin_np` instead of `pthread_cond_timedwait` to wait for the thread. Detach the thread when it times out instead. This way, you don't have to rely on cooperation from the thread

Comment: It's not clear to me _what_ you want to do to the subthread after a timeout. I like the idea of _not_ detaching and using `pthread_timedjoin_np` to detect the timeout. But, do you want the subthread to ever detach (and be reparented to the init process)? That is, do you want the subthread to continue forever? Or, do you want the parent to kill/cancel the subthread? Deliberately detaching (and reparenting to process 1) is "messy". I'd do a `pthread_cancel` followed by a [blocking] `pthread_join` ...

Comment: ... Otherwise, why not detach immediately and _not_ wait at all? That's what launcher programs for [detached] servers do. Most people expect programs to either launch a server in the background or run in the foreground (to completion). Running in the foreground and then detaching to background after some [arbitrary] timeout would seem "flaky" to a casual observer. How would the exit code for the parent be interpreted? 0=completion, 1=detached, 2=segfault, etc.? And, how do we detect/handle a detached thread that _later_ segfaults?

Comment: I, on the other hand, would *not* recommend `pthread_cancel`.  Not in any program, under any circumstances.  All functions called within a thread need to be written very carefully and intentionally to be cancellation-safe.  That's easy to mess up, and it might not even be feasible in some cases.  The high development and maintenance cost and high affinity for bugs is a bad combination, which is why the first rule of `pthread_cancel()` is "never call `pthread_cancel()`."